# MVC 5, WIF (System.IdentityModel) & ADFS not actually authenticating, errors on federated signout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, wif, adfs

I'm wading through the creation of a claims-based MVC site in Visual Studio 2013.

Some things I learned so far:

- System.Identity is in, Microsoft.Identity is out
- Many of the tutorials, including Microsoft's guides for 4.5, are out-dated.  For example, I don't believe any changes to the Project Template-generated .config file are necessary for adding modules/handlers or anything.
- There is no Microsoft built-in/add-in STS in Visual Studio 2013 as there was for 2012
- Thinktecture's EmbeddedSTS addin is oft-recommended and sounds cool, but *://EmbeddedSTS/ doesn't resolve(?? I don't get it).  Also, binary links to their IdentityServer v2- are currently broken(?)
- ADFS feature requires Windows Server 2012, a Domain, and self-signed certs - not too hard if you've done it before, but steep learning curve if you haven't.
- ADFS requires SSL - Visual Studio 2013/IIS Express 8 easily supports SSL sites, just make sure the port number is in the range :44300-44398
- ADFS manager Relying Party interface suggests examples referring to "sts" and "adfs/ls" and stuff which is, I think, misleading.  Really they should just point back to your app (`https://localhost:44300` for example).  Although mine's not working right yet, so that could be related to my mistake.
- Once you create a new Visual Studio Web Application project, there is no tooling to change the authentication mechanisms.  Just start over with a new project and change the authentication to Organizational Accounts (for on-premises, as in my case).  *Your STS, such as your ADFS installation, has to be installed and reachable in order to complete this wizard.*
- Use the `hosts` file to override DNS for the VM's IP to the expected domain name if you're hacking together a test ADFS DC in a VM because you don't have rights to join a machine to the domain.
- "Users are required to provide credentials each time the sign in" is helpful when working through sign-in sign-out problems at first.
- I don't think any claims, even identity, are passed if you don't have any Claim Rules.

### 1) What is wrong such that my app still thinks the user is not authenticated?

I'm to the point where my `https://localhost:44300/Default/Index/` action is supposed to display details of `User.Identity` (I also tried `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`) if the user is authenticated.  I have a login Action link, generated with:

```
var signIn = new SignInRequestMessage(new Uri("https://dc.ad.dev.local/adfs/ls/"), "https://localhost:44300");

return new RedirectResult(signIn.WriteQueryString());
```

Clicking this link indeed takes me to the ADFS login page.  Logging in brings me back to my application.  Watching the preserved Network activity in Chrome Bug shows that I have a `RequestSecurityTokenResponse` message being posted back to the app, but the app's `User.Identity` is still not *authenticated*.

I have one Claim Rule configured:  A "Transform an Incoming Claim" from "Windows Account Name" to "Name ID" as a "Transient Identifier".  I see the `<saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">DevAD\jdoe</saml:NameIdentifier>` represented in the sniffed `POST`.  I've tried a bunch of other Claim Rules and still don't get *authenticated*.

I don't have any custom code for absorbing the claims.  **I am expect interception of a POST with the token to any app url to be converted to the `User.Identity` auto-magically by the framework**, perhaps having been initiated by this wizard-generated code in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
app.UseActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthentication(
    new ActiveDirectoryFederationServicesBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
        MetadataEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AdfsMetadataEndpoint"]
    });
```

But part of me doubts this expectation.  Is it correct?  Is there a special known route that MVC WIF creates for accepting such login posts that I should be using besides my default route url?

### 2) How can I log out successfully?

I also have a logout action:

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri("https://dc.ad.dev.local/adfs/ls/"), new Uri(Url.Action("Index", null, null, Request.Url.Scheme)));
```

But on this `https://dc.ad.dev.local/adfs/ls?wa=wsignout1.0&wreply=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44300%2f` page, "An error occurred".  Event Viewer shows #364: "Encountered error during federation passive request."

```
Protocol Name: 
wsfed 

Relying Party: 

Exception details: 
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.AddSignoutSessionInformation(WSFederationSignOutContextBase context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.ProcessSignOut(WSFederationSignOutContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolSignoutRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

My ADFS Service > Certificates are all set to the same cert and I think are correct.

================

And by the way, the following *is* what is supposed to be *passively* posted to the app, right?  And, again, it is absorbed automatically?

```
<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
    <t:Lifetime>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2014-07-28T14:29:47.167Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2014-07-28T15:29:47.167Z</wsu:Expires>
    </t:Lifetime>
    <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            <wsa:Address>https://localhost:44300/</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:EndpointReference>
    </wsp:AppliesTo>
    <t:RequestedSecurityToken>
        <saml:Assertion MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="_e2399a27-acac-4390-aa8a-556f41fec2f2" Issuer="http://dc.ad.dev.local/adfs/services/trust" IssueInstant="2014-07-28T14:29:47.167Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion">
            <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2014-07-28T14:29:47.167Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-07-28T15:29:47.167Z">
                <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
                    <saml:Audience>https://localhost:44300/</saml:Audience>
                </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
            </saml:Conditions>
            <saml:AttributeStatement>
                <saml:Subject>
                    <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">DevAD\jdoe</saml:NameIdentifier>
                    <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                        <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                </saml:Subject>
                <saml:Attribute AttributeName="name" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
                    <saml:AttributeValue>jdoe</saml:AttributeValue>
                </saml:Attribute>
                <saml:Attribute AttributeName="givenname" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
                    <saml:AttributeValue>John Doe</saml:AttributeValue>
                </saml:Attribute>
                <saml:Attribute AttributeName="upn" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
                    <saml:AttributeValue>jdoe@ad.dev.local</saml:AttributeValue>
                </saml:Attribute>
            </saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport" AuthenticationInstant="2014-07-28T14:29:47.152Z">
                <saml:Subject>
                    <saml:NameIdentifier Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient">DevAD\jdoe</saml:NameIdentifier>
                    <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                        <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
                    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
                </saml:Subject>
            </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
                    <ds:Reference URI="#_e2399a27-acac-4390-aa8a-556f41fec2f2">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>+ZDduF0CKxXq7P+diyAXN51mo549pvwo3BNCekWSEpk=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>VMjCbSZXw3YROHYQ1eCYH5D9UQl1tzqZ9Nw99FUK78A8TSLs1ns3G8PE1d1Z1db2KKpbnzExXSXG2elP3Z69OejSWjsywIFTPeGcbGk4BvrV4ZcHGCbYKN0Wg5pySMEqm4LV1E5k+32kuALveLi5fkQROyXudquvVRgYrgu7XBsfr96Uvqo1yWmAzhhpEorfe4Z0p4RurKRpS7IsrI9SkssGOdQV/89NQelIZSZzOEMfay/AxewBbQ8C46g/4NgygaaPsG8X52EFVftzFY0BM8k+aMMUiKrJ0Xo7tJCMxJLcQ3aJdLBRNybHaklFgtln0ZCSlYylglUjUZ5d66jGcg==</ds:SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
        </saml:Assertion>
    </t:RequestedSecurityToken>
    <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
    <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
    <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
</t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```

===============

Below are the Claims defined.  As suggested by @nzpcmad, the second one now "Send LDAP Attributes as Claims" from "Active Directory" to send "SAM-Account-Name" as "Name", "Display Name" as "Given Name", and "User-Principal-Name" as "UPN".  And though the application receives the claims in the passive post, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is still false and the other `User.Identity` data are blank too.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a resolution for the error you were getting when signing out?

Comment: Hello there, any news on the issue? Have you finally resolved it?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  I gave up

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much right with your observations.

Just to note:

ADFS runs on Server 2008 R2, 2012 and 2012 R2.

Have a look at [Use the On-Premises Organizational Authentication Option (ADFS) With ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2013](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/02/12/use-the-on-premises-organizational-authentication-option-adfs-with-asp-net-in-visual-studio-2013/).

It describes exactly what you are trying to do.

In particular, have a look at the claims.

You'll see it uses "Send LDAP Attribute" rather than the Transform you use.

Comment: Thanks, I added the additional claims but it's still not working.  I added those details to the question.

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx to see how to handle IsAuthenticated.

Comment: Yes, that's the View implementation I'm using.  And the controller is adding either `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` or `User.Identity` (either should work, I believe) to the ViewBag, as shown there.  I'm not doing any of the config file stuff, per my second bullet point.

Comment: I just built a project as per the link and it works OK. I suggest you make a new project as per the link and then compare against yours to see what's different.

Comment: I will try that again (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx, that is), but even so the code generated from a brand new MVC 5 Project Template with the On-Premises Organizational Identity Authentication seems to suggest that none of those .config file changes should be necessary.

Comment: I tried applying those config file changes (and the view/controller changes that were already applied) and there is no change.  I even threw out the project and started over from scratch.  No change.  Who is responsible for receiving ADFS's post back to the application and extracting the claims?  Does that have to point to a specific "virtual" route or something?

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same sign-out issue and it seems to occur if you do not have the issuing certificate in the trusted people certificate store.